# Roles of commas

Tags: commas

I couldn't understand the role of the commas in the following sentence.

> While many of his people starve, they write, Mr. Kim “is such a connoisseur that, according to his former chef, every grain of rice destined for his dinner table is inspected for quality and shape.”

What is the gramatical role of each comma in this sentence?

Comment: To indicate a pause.  The same as any other comma.

Comment: The clauses between the pauses are parenthetical, or nearly so. You could replace them with curved brackets and the sentence would still work.

Comment: What do I have to change in this? What is wrong with it ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give you my take on this.

In the case of the commas around "they write", this is an attribution (of sorts) for the following quotation. This is intended to attribute the quote to someone other than the present writer.  The question of who "they" are is presumably answered in a preceding sentence.

The same is the case of the commas surrounding "according to his former chef".

That's all there is to it, in this case.

Comment: Is there any grammatical explanation according to the well known rules of comma use?

Answer (score 1):

Start by simplifying your original statement, substituting some symbols for bigger pieces:

> While (MPS), they write, Mr Kim is (SAC).

The first part can be considered an introductory clause or it can be seen as an inverted subordinating conjunction signaled by the word *while*. Uninverting it gives:

> They write (that) Mr. Kim is (SAC) while (MPS).

In this uninverted form, you can see another conjunction, signaled by the word *that*, which wasn't explicit in the original text.

So we have three clauses, and the two with the symbols (SAC) and (MAC) can be expanded separately. Here is (MPS) expanded:

> Many of his people starve.

This is simple enough. *His* refers to Mr. Kim.

The next one (SAC) is more complicated, so we can simplify it further:

> Mr. Kim is such a connoisseur that (EGR).

So we have another subordinating conjunction, where the subordinate clause (EGR) is:

> according to his former chef, every grain of rice destined for his dinner table is inspected for quality and shape.

This starts with an introductory clause or parenthetical clause (*according to his chef*). Or, if you chose to invert it, it would be considered a parenthetical clause.

This is indeed a complicated sentence, with many clauses. Breaking it into parts like this might help you understand it better and understand the role of the comma and the role of conjunctions in discerning the overall meaning.

Comment: Is it They write (that) Mr. Kim is (MPS) while (SAC). ?  or They write (that) Mr. Kim is (SAC) while (MPS).? It came to me a bit illogical.

Comment: I think I caught that and fixed it at the same time you were writing. Sorry about that.

Comment: It an impressive answer honestly. But really it doesent answer the reason of use of commas with return to well known rules of commas. I still couldn't understand that comma used after "they write,". Is there any rule that obliges a writer to put a comma there. If there is, what is it ? Sorry for my questions. I am not a native English speaker and I am trying my best to learn all details to be more proficient.

Comment: Commas and conjunctions are used here to separate clauses. I thought, after giving this as background, I would leave it to the reader to look further into commas, clauses, and conjunctions. The explanations of each of those should make your understanding of your question clearer, and you'll understand those three topics much better as well.

Answer (score 0):

> While many of his people starve, they write, Mr. Kim “is such a connoisseur that, according to his former chef, every grain of rice destined for his dinner table is inspected for quality and shape.

first comma: to set off the subordinate clause that commences with the subordinating conjunction "while"

second comma: to indicate a natural pause that would occur in speech, since the subordinating conjunction "that" is being omitted here

third comma and fourth comma: to set off the participial phrase "according to his former chef"